# Writing a distribution as two uniform distributions

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following distribution:

$$P(Z \leq z ) = \begin{cases} z/20 & 0 < x <10 \\
1/2 + z/200 & 10 \leq z < 110 \\
1 & z > 110
\end{cases} $$

How can I write this as a mix of two uniform distributions? For reference, the cdf of U(a,b) is (x - a)/(b - a), and the pdf is 1/(b - a).

Comment: Should $z$ be $x$? And this function can't be a cumulative distribution function since it's not increasing. Perhaps you mean for it to be a density function?

Comment: fixed @GregMartin

Comment: I think maybe it's still wrong. I'm trying to find the equilibrium distribution of a random variable that is $10$ with probability $0.1$ and $110$ with probability $0.1$. Can you help me? That is what the distribution function is supposed to be

Comment: The equilibrium distribution is $X$ is $F_{e}(x) = \frac{1}{E(X)} \int_{0}^x P(X > x)$.

Comment: If you mean the underlying variable is 10 with probability 0.9, I think you have the right formula. The probabilities 0.1 and 0.1 don't add up to 1, so that cannot be what you wanted.

Comment: @DavidK I typoed. I meant $X$ takes on $10$ with probability $0.1$ and $110$ with probability $0.9$. I want to find $F_{e}(x)$ with the formula I gave in the other comment

Comment: In that case the expected value of $X$ is $100$ and you need a different distribution than shown.